# Should Kestrel be used with a reverse proxy when running in AKS cluster?

Tags: azure, docker, asp.net-core, kubernetes

I've been reading a lot about kubernetes, docker and containers in general. There is a ton of materials on the web. Problem is that some specific but important information is hard to come by.

Right now kestrel is the default web server for asp.net core but it has some limitations (lack of functionalities) and recommended hosting option is one with use of reverse proxy. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/servers/kestrel?view=aspnetcore-2.2

This can be easily achieved on local environments for example with use of IIS. Now my question is how should it work in Azure AKS ? If I'm not mistaken right now if we would deploy using below docker kubernetes scripts Kestrel will be the hosting server in Azure.

Docker:

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet:sdk AS build-env
WORKDIR /app

RUN mkdir /output

# Copy project and publish

COPY . /app

WORKDIR /app/WebApi
RUN dotnet publish --configuration Release --output /output -nowarn:1701,1702,1591;

# Build runtime image
FROM microsoft/dotnet:aspnetcore-runtime

ENV ASPNETCORE_URLS http://*:5100

WORKDIR /app

COPY --from=build-env /output .
EXPOSE 5100

ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "WebApi.dll"]
```

Kubernetes:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: web-api
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: web-api
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: web-api
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: web-api
        image: azureadress.io/web-api:latest 
        env:
          - name: ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT
            value: "Azure_Development"
        resources:
          requests:
            cpu: 100m
            memory: 128Mi
          limits:
            cpu: 250m
            memory: 256Mi
        ports:
        - containerPort: 5100 
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  annotations:
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/load-balancer-source-ranges:  
  name: web-api
spec:
  loadBalancerIP: xxxxx.xxx.xxx
  type: LoadBalancer 
  ports:
  - port: 5100
  selector:
    app: web-api
```

Should reverse proxy also be used in this case ? I wasn't able to find any materials on how the production setup should look like.

Comment: i dont think kestrel is recommended for production, so ideally you'd need to use ingress along with kestrel, or something other than kestrel

Comment: @4c74356b41: First, Kestrel is production ready (its the only way to host ASP.NET Core outside of IIS in-process (only available since ASP.NET Core 2.2). Second, for ASP.NET Core 1.x Kestrel wasn't recommended for IFS (internet facing server) scenarios since it lacked some of the full-fledged features such as SSL, throttling and more etc. This features however were added with ASP.NET Core 2.0 and Kestrel can now also be used for IFS scenarios. But when you use docker you are gotta use reverse proxy anyways (when using docker) mainly for load balancing and easier ssl termination

Comment: never seen anyone recommend kestrel for serving traffic directly, which we are talking about here

Comment: @Tseng what about request timeout ? This is a simple feature that can be easily adressed in IIS web.config. I wasn't able to find a way to do that in Kestrel

Considering usage of reverse proxy. Anyway do you know any articles/examples of how a setup with reverse proxy should look like and what should be used when hosting applications in AKS using docker?